# best way to write out 256^3 array from fortran so matlab can read it

Tags: arrays, matlab, fortran, gfortran

I have an array I've created which is of size: 256^3.

```
real*8, dimension(256,256,256) :: dense

open(unit=8,file=fname,form="unformatted")
write(8)dense(:,:,:)
close(8)
```

What would be the best way to write this out so Matlab can read it? I have some post processing I want to use.

I am using gfortran so I can't use binary format :{ is this true? I set the form to "binary" and it doesn't recognise it. I don't have ifort installed either.

Comment: I speak Matlab, but not Fortran.  What is the most space efficient file format you can write to?  We can probably get Matlab to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the array out using unformatted stream access.  Stream access is the standard equivalent of binary.  Stealing from IRO-bot's answer:

```
real(kind=kind(0.0d0)),dimension(256,256,256) :: dense

open(unit=8,file='test.dat',& ! Unformatted file, stream access
  form='unformatted',access='stream')
write(unit=8) dense           ! Write array
close(unit=8)
end
```

This is more than likely adequate and appropriate for your needs.  Note though, that for more convoluted or complicated output requirements Matlab comes with an library of routines callable from a compiled language that allow you to write .mat files.  Other libraries also exist that can facilitate this sort of data transfer - for example HDF5.

Comment: Could you provide any code which would do this Ian? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write binary files using either `stream` access, as suggested by IanH, or `direct` access:

```
integer :: reclen
real(kind=kind(0.0d0)),dimension(256,256,256) :: dense

inquire(iolength=reclen)dense ! Inquire record length of the array dense
open(unit=8,file='test.dat',& ! Binary file, direct access
     form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=reclen)
write(unit=8,rec=1)dense      ! Write array into first record 
close(unit=8)

end
```

Unless you specify `access` attribute in the `open` statement, the file will be opened in `sequential` mode, which may be inconvenient for reading because it adds a padding to each record which contains information about record length. By using `direct` access, you are able to specify the record length explicitly, and in this case, the size of the file written will be exactly `8*256^3`, so assuming you know the array ordering and endianness, you are able to read it from your MATLAB script.

Comment: Thanks very much IRO. The write out seems to have proceeded OK. In terms of reading it in? What would be the best fopen procedure - something like: fid = fopen(filename,'rb'); mesh = fread(fid,ndim*ndim*ndim,'double'); fclose(fid); Thanks!

Comment: I don't know MATLAB, but after a quick look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html, your snippet looks right. I assume this would get you 1-d array of length ndim^3, so you may want to reshape it back to (ndim,ndim,ndim).

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that you won't get padding or some sort of record markers written to a file with direct access - its processor dependent.  Admittedly before stream access was introduced this was the most likely way to get things to work.

Comment: @IanH Section 9.6.4.5.2 of the latest standard draft describes how this is done. The number of file storage units written is determined exactly by RECL and the number of records written. The file storage unit size however, is compiler dependent, and that is why we use the INQUIRE statement. But definitely no padding here, not by standard, nor by any major compiler implementation I've used (gfortran, Intel, PGI). Please let us know if you are aware of any.

Comment: Note we are talking here about the on-disk representation of records.  9.1p4 explicitly allows for processor dependency in how record files (direct or sequential) look if they can be opened as stream (which is how C/Matlab see the file) - basically this allows the processor to write additional book keeping information to the file not visible to Fortran programs.  ifort documentation mentions one use of this if the -vms compatibility option is selected.  Likely to work with current processors - yes.  Guaranteed to work - no.

Comment: @IanH Sure, agreed. This argument can be extended to almost anything in the universe.

Comment: When I use the above code I check the variable reclen with write(*,*)reclen just after the 'inquire' line and I get 134217728 which is 512^3 - if the mesh is 256^3 (as stated in question) then why do I get 512^3 when it checks the size of dense just before write out? I think this is why I am getting errors reading it into Python for postprocessing.

Comment: Could someone provide some code for doing this in stream access please?

Comment: @Griff The reclen that you get is 8 * 256^3.  This is the number of file storage units (which is the number of bytes if you are using gfortran) needed to hold the array `dense` in IRO-bot's example.  A file written using stream access would also use that number of file storage units.  I suspect your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Right, so when I read this into Python, I won't need to declare that it is 8*256^3? This is just the length of the matrix as seen by gfortran?

Comment: @Griff In principle, you don't need to know what is the value of iolength in the inquire statement. It is a way to obtain the record length for your array, which varies between compilers, and use that value to specify the record lenght when opening a file in direct access mode.

Comment: How do I increase the length it can write out to... I have now increased the mesh size to ndim = 700 and so I am writing out a 700^3 binary file. When I go to use the exact same code which worked for lower resolution (256,512), it now fails - I mean it reads in the data, but all of the values of 0.0. Has fortran hit some write out limit? Or is this something I need to fix in Python?